# select two columns and run update query on them and do this in single query

Tags: mysql

i want to select two columns from database id and password 
and want to use those two columns data in update query 
example

```
 select id , pass from table 
second update query
update table set password2=password_get_from select_query where id=id_get_from_select_query
```

Comment: and where does php come into the picture? or you want us to do that for you? the API to connect with is unknown, so the question is both unclear and too broad; what have you tried?

Comment: i just want to create single query which will do work of both of these queries no need for php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like.

```
update table_one as A
inner join table_two AS B on (A.id = B.id)
set A.some_column = B.some_column, 
A.another_column = B.another_column
where blah
```